# !Latex error: Option clash for package geometry

Tags: document-classes, geometry, incompatibility

Hi I am getting option clash package error where as I am  declaring `geometry` package only once as below:

```
\documentclass{vldb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{balance}  % for  \balance command ON LAST PAGE  (only there!)
\usepackage[top=0.75in,left=0.80in,bottom=0.75in,right=0.80in]{geometry}


\newtheorem{Definition}{Definition}[section]
\newtheorem{Deff}{Definition}
\newtheorem{Lemma}{Lemma} [section]
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}

\newcounter{example}[section]
\newenvironment{example}[1][]{\refstepcounter{example}\par\medskip
   \noindent \textbf{Example~\theexample. #1} \rmfamily}{\medskip}

\begin{document}
```

Could you please help here?

Comment: Are you compiling with pdflatex?

Comment: Welcome! Presumably, the class you are using already loads the package. Try removing the `\usepackage...{geometry}` line and configuring with just `\geometry{...}`. Note that this cannot be confirmed as I have no idea where `vldb.cls` is or what is in it.

Comment: Try adding `\PassOptionsToPackage{top=0.75in,left=0.80in,bottom=0.75in,right=0.80in}{geometry}` before `\documentclass`.

Comment: Delete the line `\usepackage[top=0.75in,left=0.80in,bottom=0.75in,right=0.80in]{geometry}` and load the class like this: `\documentclass[top=0.75in,left=0.80in,bottom=0.75in,right=0.80in]{vldb}`

Answer (score 8):

Apparently the class `vldb` is already loading `geometry` with settings different from what you'd like to get.

If the class is for submissions to a journal or a conference, don't set new values for `geometry`. Otherwise simply do

```
\geometry{top=0.75in,left=0.80in,bottom=0.75in,right=0.80in}
```

where you have `\usepackage[...]{geometry}`. The new values will override those set by the class.